# How to send push-notifications in local wireless network without accessing internet (FCM)?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, networking, push-notification

I'm working on a security project in which many android devices should communicate with each other via local server & local wireless network. I also need push notifications to be implemented, but the problem is that I don't have access to the internet, so I can't use FCM or any related system like one-signal or Pushy.

I tried using android services(react-native-background-fetch) & socket-io. but it only fires connection every 15 minutes and doesn't maintain the connection. this way I can only poll for new notifications from the server every 15 minutes. what should I do? is it even possible?